# I have two functions but the last one will fire

Tags: javascript, function, xmlhttprequest

I have two similar functions but only the last one will fire

I see console.log for both but the xmlhttp.open on headset(); does not actually fire. When I comment out the lineOpen(); function, then it works.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
function headset(){
xmlhttp.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/Way2Call/Way2CallService/UseHeadset?bUseHeadset=true", true);
xmlhttp.send();
console.log("Headset Set");
}
function lineOpen(){
xmlhttp.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/Way2Call/Way2CallService/Open", true);
xmlhttp.send();
console.log("Line Opened");
}
headset();
lineOpen();
```

Comment: You need to post some code in the post in case external link will be deleted later on.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin gotchu brah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get different XMLHttp Objects:

```
function getXMLHttpObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}

function headset() {
    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttpObject();

    xmlHttp.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/Way2Call/Way2CallService/UseHeadset?bUseHeadset=true", true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}

function lineOpen() {
    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttpObject();

    xmlHttp.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/Way2Call/Way2CallService/Open", true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}

headset();
lineOpen();
```

Comment: Ahhh of course. That did it. Thanks for the amazingly quick help.

Answer (score 3):

You're sharing an `xmlhttp` reference between your functions. Localize that and you should be fine.

```
function _xhr() {
    return (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function headset(){
    var xmlhttp = _xhr();
    xmlhttp.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/Way2Call/Way2CallService/UseHeadset?    bUseHeadset=true", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    console.log("Headset Set");
}
function lineOpen(){
    var xmlhttp = _xhr();
    xmlhttp.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/Way2Call/Way2CallService/Open", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    console.log("Line Opened");
}
headset();
lineOpen();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-using the same `XMLHttpRequest` for each function, before the first one has had chance to complete.

Either give each function its own `XMLHttpRequest` object:

```
function makeXMLHttpRequest() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}

function headset(){
    var xmlhttp = makeXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/Way2Call/Way2CallService/UseHeadset?bUseHeadset=true", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    console.log("Headset Set");
}

function lineOpen() {
    var xmlhttp = makeXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("get", "http://localhost:8080/Way2Call/Way2CallService/Open", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    console.log("Line Opened");
}

headset();
lineOpen();
```

or don't fire the second function until the first request has completed.

Answer (score 1):

You should not, in general re-use your xmlHttpRequest objects.

[[http://ajaxian.com/archives/the-xmlhttprequest-reuse-dilemma](This](http://ajaxian.com/archives/the-xmlhttprequest-reuse-dilemma%5d%28This) link) goes into it in some detail.

I'd suggest you create a function which does something like:

```
    function doRequest(){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open(type, url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

You can also create a function that simply returns a request object for you to use.

```
    function getRequest(){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return(xmlhttp);
    }
```

Or just use jQuery! :)